# Mock anonymous inner class

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have one anonymous inner class whom i want to mock. lets say `Hey$Bro` whose function that is `getName()` . How can i mock this class.

`Mockito.doReturn(null).when(Mockito.mock(Hey.Bro.class).getName());`

this throws me below error

```
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
```

What to do in this scenario?

Comment: How can the class have a name if it is anonymous? --- The code you provided, ven if it worked, would be useless since you create a mock and then do not use it further. --- This very much sounds like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to mock the anonymous class?

Comment: Can't you just mock the base class or implemented interface of the anonymous inner class?